# MySQL join returning redundant data

Tags: php, mysql

I am building an auction website. Right now, I am building the item description page, that has item details, as well as current bid history. My bids table has a FK of Item_id.

My current query looks something like this:

```
SELECT bids.Item_id, bids.User_email, bids.Bid_amount, products.*
FROM bids
INNER JOIN products
ON bids.Item_id=products.Item_id;
```

This returns all of the bid information I need - but also returns the item description for every bid row. I only need the product information once. Is it best to just use two queries on this?

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need the `bids` data separately from the `products` data, then you should use two queries.

One query cannot really be arrange to return different columns for different rows.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT b.Item_id, b.User_email, b.Bid_amount, p.*
FROM bids b
INNER JOIN products p
ON b.Item_id=p.Item_id
WHERE p.Item_id=something;
```

This will not repeat products..